# Rails: where to place custom class injections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, project-organization

i wrote some helper methods for my application like this

```
module Magick
  class Draw
    def qrcode(qrcode, left_corner, top_corner, right_corner, bottom_corner)
      size = qrcode.modules.length
      width = right_corner - left_corner
      height = bottom_corner - top_corner
      wset = width.to_f / size
      hset = height.to_f / size
...............
```

Where to place such code in rails ?

Comment: I put them in 'lib/monkeypatching' and load them with an initializer

Comment: Monkey patching.. i just didnt know how to call this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common and easy way to load those patches is to create a file inside your ./config/initializers directory (ie: rmagick.rb) and put your code in this file.

All files in this directory are loaded and executed on environment startup.

You could also create a new file with your code in the lib/ directory (ie: rmagick_draw.rb) and add this line in ./config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

And then require the file anywhere you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put such files into ***app\classes*** directory. All classes from this directory are available by default in Rails3.